# how do you extract column names that match any of the character in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have this data frame called t:

```
dput(t)
structure(list(Server = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Server1", "Server2", "Server3", "Server4"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "7/17/2017 15:01", "7/17/2017 15:02", "7/17/2017 15:03", 
    "7/17/2017 15:04"), class = "factor"), Host_CPU = c(1.161323547, 
    6.966178894, 0.656402588, 0.555137634, NA, NA), UsedMemPercent = c(11.33, 
    11.38, 11.38, 11.38, NA, NA), MY_REPORTING_NYAPP = c(1.05, 
    0.65, 0.52, 0.32, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Server", "Date", 
"Host_CPU", "UsedMemPercent", "MY_REPORTING_NYAPP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I need to be able to grep the names of the columns that may include any of the string separated by under score.

For example,

```
app<-c("MY_NYAPP")
```

I need to grep if any of the words in app vector separated by "_" and assigned it to var.

```
app1<-unlist(strsplit(app, "_"))

var<-grep(app1,names(t), value=TRUE)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `t[grep('_', names(t))]`?

Comment: @alistaire, I need to have app1 that has all the words separated by "_", then var=any of the values in app1 matches the column names.

Comment: `grep(paste(unlist(strsplit(grep('_', names(t), value = TRUE), '_')), collapse = '|'), names(t), value = TRUE)`? It seems pretty pointless, though; you should ask your question with a desired result and a context large enough to point you towards a more direct approach.

Comment: `grep(sub('_','|','MY_NYAPP'), names(t))` is shorter. This will return the indexes of those columns that have either "MY" or "NYAPP" in their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to check which columnnames contain both "MY" and "APP" if the input is "MY_APP"?

```
t = structure(list(Server = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
                                                                        "Server1", "Server2", "Server3", "Server4"), class = "factor"), 
               Date = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
                                                                      "7/17/2017 15:01", "7/17/2017 15:02", "7/17/2017 15:03", 
                                                                      "7/17/2017 15:04"), class = "factor"), Host_CPU = c(1.161323547, 
                                                                                                                          6.966178894, 0.656402588, 0.555137634, NA, NA), UsedMemPercent = c(11.33, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             11.38, 11.38, 11.38, NA, NA), MY_REPORTING_NYAPP = c(1.05, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.65, 0.52, 0.32, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Server", "Date", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Host_CPU", "UsedMemPercent", "MY_REPORTING_NYAPP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -6L))

app<-c("MY_NYAPP")

app2 = unlist(strsplit(app,"_"))
colnames(t)[rowSums(sapply(app2, function(x) grepl(x,colnames(t))))==length(app2)]
```

which returns:

```
[1] "MY_REPORTING_NYAPP"
```

Hope this helps.